# Polly in base class execute abstract method with paramter

Tags: c#, polly

I'm trying to add Polly policy in a base class. The problem is that the method I want to retry is an abstract method with a parameter, and the children classes define that parameter. Code sample:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{   
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        // original code
        // someEvent += OnChange;
        someEvent += OnChangeBase;      
    }

    private void OnChangeBase()
    {
        var policy = GetRetryPolicy();
        // how do I use the bool parameter from children class?
        policy.Execute(() => OnChange(??));
    }

    protected abstract void OnChange(bool param);
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with standard abstract class patterns. The solution isn't particularly different because Polly is involved.

You could just add to the base class:

```
protected abstract bool GetBoolParameterValue(); // choose a name more meaningful to your use case
```

And then the code line executing through the policy becomes:

```
policy.Execute(() => OnChange(GetBoolParameterValue()));
```

This uses an abstract method, but you could also use an abstract property; or a bool field defined on the base class.

---

Alternatively: The question presents that the signature of `OnChangeBase` is `OnChangeBase()`.  But if the original signature of `OnChange` was `OnChange(bool)`, can you just do this?

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{   
    protected BaseClass()
    {
        // original code
        // someEvent += OnChange;
        someEvent += OnChangeBase;      
    }

    private void OnChangeBase(bool foo)
    {
        var policy = GetRetryPolicy();
        policy.Execute(() => OnChange(foo));
    }

    protected abstract void OnChange(bool param);
}
```

Comment: This changes the way it works. This base class's children are references everywhere. I don't want to make code changes everywhere. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I can't think of a different way to achieve what the question directly asked. You want the base class to access things only defined in child classes. To do that, you _have_ to create some reference to those things/to get them (abstract method; abstract property; bool field) in the base class. Alternatively, you could change the signature of `OnChange` to `protected abstract void OnChange()` and have the child classes call on locally to `OnChangeInternal(bool)`.  .

Comment: Or there are other things you could do, such as define this method on the base class: `protected void ExecuteWithRetry(Action action) => GetRetryPolicy().Execute(action);`. Child classes then call back into it passing their `OnChange(bool)` as `action`. But then child classes have to remember to call it (it doesn't enforce it in the base class).

Comment: Added another alternative to the main answer

Comment: The alternative was what I end up doing